# Go equivalent of Perl 5 utf::decode

Tags: json, go, unicode, utf-8

What is the equivalent to this Perl program, in Go?

```
use utf8;
my $bin = "..."; # the data may came from file, network, etc
utf8::decode( $bin ); # Encode::decode( 'UTF-8', $bin ) also works
```

defined in http://perldoc.perl.org/utf8.html

I try several forms of transformation/ normalization/ convert to bytes/runes/etc without success.

Context:

I am using Sereal ( https://github.com/Sereal/Sereal ) to serialize some data structures in a NoSQL database, first we had a Perl 5.12.2 version, them we are using Go. Sereal format is a binary

However, somehow, some perl programs made an extra JSON encode/decode on the final BLOB (in a UTF-8 string), so it is fine for perl programs read and write data, but when Go try to decode it does not work.

Of course, the best solution is *stop* this double encoding, but since we have entries in our database with this format I want to see if I can try to decode it

Proof-of-Concept - here is my Json with an utf-8 converted string from my sereal bytes

```
$ hexdump -C min.bin 
00000000  22 3d c3 b3 72 6c 5c 75  30 30 30 33 5c 75 30 30  |"=..rl\u0003\u00|
00000010  30 30 51 6b 6c 61 73 74  5f 75 70 64 61 74 65 20  |00Qklast_update |
00000020  c2 82 c3 9a c3 a6 c3 93  5c 75 30 30 30 35 22     |........\u0005"|
0000002f
```

decode.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;
use Sereal::Decoder;
use Data::Dumper;
use File::Slurp;

my $data = read_file( "min.bin", { binmode => ':raw' } );
my $bin = JSON->new->allow_nonref(1)->decode( $data );
utf8::decode( $bin ); # MAGIC !!!
my $out = Sereal::Decoder->new->decode( $bin );
print(Dumper( $out ));
```

output

```
$VAR1 = {
          'last_update' => 1517923586
        };
```

decode.go

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"

    "github.com/Sereal/Sereal/Go/sereal"
    "github.com/davecgh/go-spew/spew"
)

func main() {
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("min.bin")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("unexpected error while reading fixtures file: '%+v'\n", err)
    }
    var v interface{}
    err = json.Unmarshal(data, &v)
    spew.Dump(v, err)

    var vbody interface{}
    instance := sereal.NewDecoder()
    instance.PerlCompat = false
    str := v.(string)
    // something here to be able to decode?
    err = instance.Unmarshal([]byte(str), vbody)
    spew.Dump(vbody, err)
}
```

output

```
(string) (len=30) "=órl\x03\x00Qklast_update \u0082ÚæÓ\x05"
(interface {}) <nil>
(interface {}) <nil>
(*errors.errorString)(0xc42000e370)(bad header: it seems your document was accidentally UTF-8 encoded)
```

edit: this code works, but I think it is not the proper way:

```
  buff := &bytes.Buffer{}
  for len(s) > 0 {
     r, size := utf8.DecodeRuneInString( s )
     buff.WriteByte( byte(r ) ) 
     s = s[size:]
  }

  rawBytes := buff.Bytes() // yeah
```

Regards

Tiago

Comment: That's not UTF-8, that's ASCII with literal escape sequences. Your text actually contains e.g. the string `\u0003`.

Comment: yes @Adrian but when I convert the original content ( json ) I find an UTF-8 String but I need raw bytes. ex: if I find 0xC3 and 0xB3 I need convert to 0xF3

Comment: Where is the quoted output coming from? I only see three printing statements, one of which (the error logging) isn't being executed, so only two of the four lines of output are accounted for, and it's not clear what's what. Also if e.g. you know that `v` will be a `string`, why are you unmarshalling into `interface{}` and doing a type conversion?

Comment: Your comparison to `utf8::decode` is just confusing matters. That function is rather specific to Perl's Unicode implementation. I don't think it's applicable at all to Go, and certainly not to this situation.